# Downloading file from redirection link python

Tags: python, redirect, nginx, download, python-3.6

I am trying to make a simple program that will help with the confusing part of rooting.

I need to download the file from tiny.cc/latestmagisk

I am using this python code

```
import request
url = tiny.cc/latestmagisk

r = request.get(url)
r.content
```

The content it returns is the usual 403 Forbidden for nginx

I need this to work with the shortened URL is there anyway to make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

its's not necessary to import request lib
all you need to do is `import ssl, urllib` and pass `ssl._create_unverified_context()` as context to the server while you're sendig a request!

your code should be look like this:

```
import ssl, urllib

certcontext = ssl._create_unverified_context()
f = open('image.jpg','wb') #creating placeholder

#creating image from url and saving it as `image.jpg`!
f.write(urllib.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKh7E.png", context=certcontext).read())

f.close()
```

**note:** it will save the image as `image.jpg` file ..

Comment: thanks. but what I meant is the link tiny.cc/latestmagisk in the image. its a URL shortener and I couldn't find a way to post the shortened URL. is there anyway to get tiny.cc/latestmagisk to work?

edit: ive edited my question and now i can post the shortened URL. if you could please look it over again that would be very helpful. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the other answer, you really *should* use `requests` for this as `requests` has better support for redirects.

For getting a page through a redirect from requests:

```
r=requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
```

For downloading files through redirects:

```
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, stream=True)
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
        if chunk: f.write(chunk)
```

However, in this case, either tiny.cc or XDA does not allow a simple requests.get; the 403 forbidden is likely due to the `User-Agent` or other intrinsic header as this method works well with bit.ly and other shortlink generators. You may need to fake headers.